# Magento : Disable Shipping Methods based on custom attribute for product

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods

I created a custom attribute for products in admin panel for shipping Information having values "Yes" or "No"

1. If value is "No" then need to hide (disable) shipping method for the particular product.
2. If value is "Yes" then need to show shipping method for the particular product.

On a cart page (template\checkout\cart.phtml), I put the condition that if shipping is set "No" (for particular product) then no need to show shipping and if "Yes" then show shipping form.

Its working good but on "Placing a order", I am getting shipping error saying that "Please fill shipping details".

I am confused what I need to do.
I hope, anyone can solve my problem.
Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: For these cases,you can create the virtual products.

Comment: Shipping methods are visible in checkout or hidden from there as well?